# Why is the browse tab for some tables in phpmyadmin disabled?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

This may be a very basic question, but why is it when I'm using phpmyadmin I can browse the data in some tables, but in other tables the browse tab is disabled?

The database I'm currently looking at is for a Joomla website, but I've noticed it on other sites as well.

There is data in the tables I would like to check, but I can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'browse' tab is disabled when the table is empty (or, to be more precise, the table was empty when you loaded the page).

Comment: Thank you, I thought there might be a simple explanation!